# Matplotlib fig.savefig failing to save all subplots of my figure in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a script in jupyter notebook to process and plot some data. My figures display correctly inline in the notebook but the saved versions only contain one of the subplots.
A simplified version of my code looks like (I took out the lines that set the format of my figure for simplification):

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax = df_outlet_hmc_cluster.plot(kind='scatter', x='Time2flow', y='Depth2GW', c='cluster', cmap='viridis', linewidth=0, alpha=0.8)
ax.set_title('Outlet')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)
df_upstream_hmc_cluster.plot(ax=ax2, kind='scatter', x='Time2flow', y='Depth2GW', c='cluster', cmap='viridis', linewidth=0, alpha=0.8)
ax2.set_title('Upstream')

fig.savefig(os.path.join(figures_dir, 'Fig2.Time2flowVsDepth2GW_CLUSTER.tif'), bbox_inches='tight')
```

Any ideas on what might be the issue and how to get around it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code you posted does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems you are not creating several subplots (`111` is a single subplot). Can you make your case reproducible for others, see [mcve]?